# Thread blocks window wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

При запуске и нажатие кнопки блокируется окно. Смысл этой мини программа в том, чтобы постепенно изменялся цвет кнопки для этого я сделал задержку в цикле. Использовал анонимный метод, созданный через `Disspatcer`.

Как заблокировать один поток не блокируя другой? Если не блокировать, то цвет всегда будет последнем то есть желтым. Вопрос, как с задержкой  выводить цвета? Как я понимаю мой вариант задержки не верный.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private delegate void Del();

    private Thread _thread;
    private static Brush _brush;

    private delegate void dell();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Webbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(ColorsMove);
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void ColorsMove()
    {
        Webbtn.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            (ThreadStart) delegate
            {
                var c = MessageBox.Show("Hello ", "People", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                if (c == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    _brush = Webbtn.Background;
                    var brushesType = typeof (Brushes);

                    // Get all static properties
                    var enumColor = brushesType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

                    lock (enumColor)
                    {
                        foreach (var color in enumColor)
                        {
                            this.Background = (SolidColorBrush) color.GetValue(null, null);
                            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                        }
                    }
                }                  
                else
                {
                    Background = _brush;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос был мной исправлен

Comment: вы сами же и блокируете поток на 2 секунды. `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));`

Comment: Выбранный Вами подход совершено неверен и даже ошибочен. Про блокирование потоков уже написали в комментарии выше. Почитайте про анимацию в `WPF`, она очень для таких целей и создана

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispatcher не нужно вызывать для всего тела функции потока, иначе смысла в нем нету, блокируется весь UI поток.  вызывайте только там где требуется сделать действие в UI.
И lock не совсем понятно для чего, если для запрета повторного запуска - это лучше в Button_Click сделать, проверить инициализирован ли _thread и его состояние выполнен он или нет

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private delegate void Del();

    private Thread _thread;
    private static Brush _brush;

    private delegate void dell();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Webbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {  
        // Инициализировать лучше здесь в UI потоке чем доставать значение уже в новом потоке
        _brush = Webbtn.Background;

        Thread thread = new Thread(ColorsMove);
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void ColorsMove()
    {



         var c = MessageBox.Show("Hello ", "People", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            if (c == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {

               var brushesType = typeof(Brushes);

                // Get all static properties
                var enumColor = brushesType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

                foreach (var color in enumColor)
                {
                    Webbtn.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        new Action(()=>
                            this.Background = (SolidColorBrush) color.GetValue(null, null)));

                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                } 


                }

                else
                {
                    Background = _brush;

                }

    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам ,Вы правы