# Доступ к элементам главного окна из вторичного потока

Tags: c#, wpf

Столкнулся с проблемой доступа к ячейкам контейнера Grid, и другим элементам (TextBox например) из дополнительного потока.
Только начинаю изучать WPF, поэтому не судите строго :)
В конструкторе MainWindow запускаю поток :

```
Thread hunter = new Thread(Hunt);

hunter.Start();
```

Сам метод:

```
private void Hunt()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Grid.SetColumn(Apple, 8);
        Grid.SetRow(Apple, 4);
        Box.Text = "Привет!";
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Метод примитивен, нужно что бы дополнительный поток сам писал 
что - то в текст бокс, и переставлял картинку (Apple) в нужную мне ячейку Grid (логика смены ячеек пока не важна, но это будет скорее всего обычный Random, ну и текст будет меняться)

При попытке запустить такое выдает System.InvalidOperationException"
 Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток.

Как обойти данное ограничение? Главный поток использует эти элементы и никак не хочет ими делиться :) 
Но очень нужно работать с главным окном из другого потока в режиме "сам делает"
Подскажите решение пожалуйста!

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/418461/204383

Comment: @S.Kost спасибо, буду копать в async-await, и класс Progress, как я понял банально Thread ' ом не обойтись...

Comment: да, лучше пользоваться  async-await.

Comment: Вам по идее сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615113/10105

Comment: @VladD как раз то что нужно! Благодарю!

Comment: @SergeyD: Отлично, тогда отмечу как дубликат.