# вывод элементов List в label c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма, в которой при  выборе опред. radiobutton и нажатия кнопки "начало"  открывается новая форма. В зависимости от radiobutton на форме должны появляться с определенным интервалом элементы list1 и list2 в лейблах.

```
switch (main.passingText)
{
    case "Цвета":

        for (int i = 0; i < main.list1.Count; i++)
        {
            label_word.Text = main.list1[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < main.list2.Count; j++)
            {
                label_transl.Text = main.list2[j];
                Thread.Sleep((main.passText_forTime));

            }
        }
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` будет блочить UI поток у вас и форма будет неотзывчивая.

Comment: И как тогда исправить?

Comment: Используйте `async`/`await` конструкцию и обращайтесь к UI потоку, когда вам надо будет обновить UI контрол :)

Comment: А проще нельзя??

Comment: Можно поговнокодить и запилить конструкцию с таймером, но я вам этого делать категорически не советую

Comment: Если бы вы использовали WPF - у вас легко получилось бы реализовать биндинг

Comment: Влепить `Application.DoEvents();`...

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615113/10105

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему Thread.Sleep ведёт себя неправильно? Как мне сделать задержку или длинные вычисления в графической программе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615113/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-thread-sleep-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%91%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2):

Как уже сказали в комментариях, используйте `async/await`.

Замените строку

```
Thread.Sleep((main.passText_forTime));
```

на строку

```
await Task.Delay(main.passText_forTime);
```

При этом добавьте ключевое слово `async` к сигнатуре метода.

Comment: При попытке апдейта UI контрола будет валится эксепшн.

Comment: @AGS17 - это ж не в отдельном потоке запускается, а в gui-потоке по баттон-клику.

Comment: Прочитайте про `async`/`await` конструкции.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, также ничего не отображается на форме

Comment: @JuliaPonomareva - тогда показывайте больше кода. Это должно работать.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `async`/`await` конструкцию:

Замените все `Thread.Sleep();` на `await Task.Delay()`. Не забудьте указать `async` методу. [Познакомиться поближе](https://www.dotnetperls.com/async).

При апдейте UI контролов вам следует переходить в UI поток:

```
Invoke(() => label_transl.Text = main.list2[j]);
```

Подробнее про [`Control.Invoke()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx).

Comment: `Application.Current` - это из WPF.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ваша правда, исправил.

Comment: Всё  равно не работает

Comment: @JuliaPonomareva не работает что? Дебажить умеете?

Comment: Ничего не появляется, метод вообще не проверяется

Comment: @JuliaPonomareva ясно. Дебажте с самого старта (с обработчика нажатия кнопки "начало") и смотрите,чего оно не достигает этого кода