# Как запустить Task в Thread

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть метод который должен работать в потоке и вне потока.

```
  var regionId = comboItems.Value;
  Thread myNewThread = new Thread(() => Analyze(phrases, regionId));
  myNewThread.Start();

  DeleteStopWords();
  LoadDataToGrids();
```

Как сделать так чтобы метод DeleteStopWords ждал пока поток закончит выполнение?

Comment: А почему отдельный поток? У вас UI-приложение?

Comment: Если да, вам сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615113/10105

Comment: Да, у меня отдельный UI поток

Comment: Тогда это дубликат. Попробуйте то, как описано в ответе на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615113/10105 (смотрите кусок «А что делать, если вместо задержки нужно выполнить какие-то вычисления?»). Помогло?