# Показать обработку в реальном времени

Tags: c#, массивы, while

Всем привет.

Есть массив, в котором ссылки на файлы, есть label и есть функция для обработки файлов. Мне нужно показать какой файл я сейчас обрабатываю в label.

Пример:

```
string[] arr = {"C:\\Windows\\wine.bat", "C:\\Windows\\lacky.bat", ...};
int i = 0;
while (i != arr.Lenght) {
    label1.Text = arr[i];
    FinInFile(arr[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Проблема в том, что файл-то оно обработает, но в label не покажет, только последний. Как исправить?

Comment: Я бы для таких задачь использовал консоль

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615113/10105

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как верно подмечено в соседнем ответе, не хватает `i++` в цикле `while`. И наверно цикл `for` лучше подойдет, но это все равно не поможет. Если обработка файлов происходит быстро, вывод в лабел названий файлов не имел бы смысла, по этому будем считать, что обработка занимает какое-то время. В таком случае, если обработка будет происходит в основном потоке, то окно формы зависнет и ничего обновляться не будет. По этому, обработку нужно производить асинхронно:

```
void FinInFile(string fileName)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);//Имитируем обработку файла, который занимает 3 сек
}
private async void MyMethod()
{
    string[] arr = { "C:\\Windows\\wine.bat", "C:\\Windows\\lacky.bat", "C:\\Windows\\lacky2.bat", "C:\\Windows\\lacky3.bat", "C:\\Windows\\lacky4.bat" };
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        label1.Text = arr[i];
        await Task.Run(() => FinInFile(arr[i]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] arr = {"C:\\Windows\\wine.bat", "C:\\Windows\\lacky.bat", ...};
int i = 0;
while (i != arr.Lenght) {
    label1.Text = arr[i];
    FinInFile(arr[i]);
}
```

Вы не где не прибавляете к i еденицу, для таких задачь лучше использовать for

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Lenght; i++)
{
    label.Text = arr[i];
    FinInFile(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Забыл добавить. Оно ничего не меняет, при обработке файла в функции - не показывает текущий файл в label.
Enumerate/Threads возможно что-то в эту сторону...