# Синхронизация для поочередной смены фона областей C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, synchronized

Есть программа, которая делит форму на 6 панелей. Как с помощью синхронизации можно сделать так, чтобы через каждые 3 секунды менялся цвет у первой панели, а в ответ на изменение цвета в первой панели, вторая панель с задержкой в 5 секунд поменяла свой цвет на идентичный цвет первой части.Каждая последующая часть зависит от предыдущей (3 от 2, 4 от 3 и т.д.)
Проблема в том, что первая панель и вторая панель меняют цвета одновременно в моем коде, а нужно с задержками.

```
 Random rand = new Random();
    public System.Threading.Timer timer1;
    public Color c;   
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(AsyncHandler);
        t.Start(); 
        c = Color.FromArgb(rand.Next(255), rand.Next(255), rand.Next(255));`

        panel1.BackColor = c;
        panel2.BackColor = c;
        panel3.BackColor = c;
        panel4.BackColor = c;
        panel5.BackColor = c;
        panel6.BackColor = c;

    public void changecolor() {

    c = Color.FromArgb(rand.Next(255), rand.Next(255), rand.Next(255));
    panel1.BackColor = c;}

         private void AsyncHandler(object data)
    { this.InvokeIfNeeded(
      () => changecolor()
      );

    }
     //обработчик события на смену фона у первой панели
     private void panel1_BackColorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {this.InvokeIfNeeded(
     () => panel2.BackColor = panel1.BackColor
     );
     }
```

Comment: А где в вашем коде задержки? И для чего вам отдельный поток?

Comment: Задержку делала через Thread.Sleep() в событии изменения цвета первой панельки и она не работала - буду признательна если подскажете почему.  А вот поток действительно лишний)

Comment: Задержка с Thread.Sleep не работала по причинам, расписанным [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615113/10105).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, многопоточность для решения UI-задач — не самый лучший вариант. Все действия должны проводиться в UI-потоке. Для ожидания нужно использовать либо таймеры (традиционный вариант), либо async/await (современный подход).

```
Random random = new Random();
Color GetRandomColor() =>
    Color.FromArgb(random.Next(255), random.Next(255), random.Next(255));

private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Color c = GetRandomColor();

    panel1.BackColor = c;
    panel2.BackColor = c;
    panel3.BackColor = c;
    panel4.BackColor = c;
    panel5.BackColor = c;
    panel6.BackColor = c;

    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        Color newColor = GetRandomColor();
        SetPanelColors(newColor); // запустить асинхронную последовательность изменений
    }
}

private async void SetPanelColors(Color color)
{
    panel1.BackColor = color;
    await Task.Delay(1000); // задержка в секунду
    panel2.BackColor = color;
    await Task.Delay(2000); // задержка в 2 секунды
    panel3.BackColor = color;
    // и т. д.
}
```

---

Для пуристов, можно сделать ожидание равным трём секундам более точно, исправив цикл на

```
    while (true)
    {
        var waitTask = Task.Delay(3000);
        Color newColor = GetRandomColor();
        SetPanelColors(newColor);
        await waitTask;
    }
```

---

Как верно подсказывает @tym32167, в случае, если ваша форма — не главная, и приложение будет «жить» после её закрытия, цикл будет также продолжаться. Для этого случая нужно проверять, не закрыта ли форма:

```
    while (true)
    {
        var waitTask = Task.Delay(3000);
        if (this.IsDisposed)
            return;
        Color newColor = GetRandomColor();
        SetPanelColors(newColor);
        await waitTask;
    }
```

---

Дальнейший текст — для патологических случаев (у вас есть много форм в приложении, и вы почему-то хотите предотвратить обращение и Dispose-нутой форме, несмотря на то, что установка цветов и без этого не падает). В нормальных случаях вам этот изврат не нужен.

Итак, обратите внимание, что код может менять цвет и после закрытия формы. Чтобы этого не произошло, самый простой путь — добавить проверки после каждого `await`:

```
private async void SetPanelColors(Color color)
{
    if (this.IsDisposed)
        return;
    panel1.BackColor = color;
    await Task.Delay(1000); // задержка в секунду
    if (this.IsDisposed)
        return;
    panel2.BackColor = color;
    if (this.IsDisposed)
        return;
    await Task.Delay(2000); // задержка в 2 секунды
    if (this.IsDisposed)
        return;
    panel3.BackColor = color;
    // и т. д.
}
```

Можно исхитриться и выделить код в цикл:

```
List<(Control, int)> panelsAndDelays;
private async void SetPanelColors(Color color)
{
    foreach (var (panel, delay) in panelsAndDelays)
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
            return;
        panel.BackColor = color;
        await Task.Delay(delay);
    }
}
```

и инициализировать список заранее:

```
panelsAndDelays = new List<(Control, int)>()
{
    (panel1, 1000),
    (panel2, 2000),
    // ...
};
```

но это кажется мне уже перебором и излишней абстракцией.

Comment: Огромное(!) вам спасибо за подробное объяснение и разные варианты кода - пойду изучать новую информацию для себя) Вариант со списком мне очень даже импонирует, обычно всегда стараюсь оптимизировать и уменьшить код в конце.

Comment: @Miriam: Пожалуйста! Рад, если покажется полезным!

Answer (score 1):

Вот простой пример с заменой цветов. Первая панель меняет цвет по таймеру, вторая - через секунду после первой.

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    Panel panel1;
    Panel panel2;

    System.Threading.Timer timer;

    Random random = new Random();

    public MyForm()
    {
        panel1 = new Panel();
        panel2 = new Panel();

        panel1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        panel2.BackColor = Color.Red;

        panel1.Size = new Size(50, 100);
        panel2.Size = new Size(100, 50);

        this.Controls.Add(panel1);
        this.Controls.Add(panel2);

        panel1.BackColorChanged+=panel1_colorChanged;
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(Callback, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

        this.FormClosing+= (sender, args) => timer.Dispose();       
    }

    void Callback(object state)
    {
        var color = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(255), random.Next(255), random.Next(255));
        panel1.Invoke(new Action(() => { panel1.BackColor = color; }));
    }   

    async void panel1_colorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var color = panel1.BackColor;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        panel2.BackColor = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66634/discussion-on-answer-by-tym32167------).