# Вопрос по C# автоматизация и зависание

Tags: c#

Уважаемые гуру помогите с вопросами.
Недавно начал изучать С# в связке с Visual Studio и вот написал программку FormApss.

В программке получилась куча кнопок, у каждой кнопки свой метод `private name void` , т.е нажимая кнопки последовательно одну за одной , программка выполняет то, что мне нужно.

Запускает браузер/Авторизуется/Получает и сортирует мне необходимые данные и все ожидания везде выдержаны.

1 вопрос: Как заставить всё это работать на одну кнопку "Пуск" ?

Создаю кнопку "Пуск" с объявлением каждого метода один за одним и сыпятся ошибки - "отсутствует аргумент" - как понять какие аргументы передать ?

2 вопрос: Когда программка выполняет действия, она зависает пока не выполнит всё, её даже не сдвинуть с места. Как реализовать, чтобы ничего не висло ?

P/S код дать не могу, он громоздкий и куча личных данных.

Но что бы понять меня: Я просто создавал кнопку в конструкторе, вешал на неё задачу и так одну за одной, но думал что потом я просто запихну названия всех этих кнопок (методов) в одну и они будут выполоняться автоматезировано.

Comment: ну как максимально простое решение - перенести весь код из этих "кнопок" в одну "кнопку"

Comment: да, точно, видимо перегрелся xD - это как вариант
- Но вот как правильно оперировать этими методами между собой ? что необходимо понять/изучит ?
- Как сделать так, что бы программка не подвисала пока работает ?

Comment: чтоб не подвисал интерфейс нужно выполнять всё в другом потоке, но это наверняка слишком сложно будет сейчас для понимания

Comment: просто посмотрите примеры с асинхронным выполнением `async/await`

Comment: Посмотрите сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615113/10105