# обновление UI в потоке из ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

При попытке использовать в отдельном потоке вылетает ошибка `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ""Задание свойства "System.Windows.Controls.Image.Source" вызвало исключение.": номер строки "25" и позиция в строке "13"."` Причем если обновление данных в `textbox`, то все работает нормально, а если в `image`, то вылетает указанная ошибка.

Exeption:   `InnerException {"Необходимо создать DependencySource в том же потоке, в котором создан DependencyObject."} System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}`

Stack Trace:
`StackTrace  "   в System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)\r\n   в System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)\r\n   в System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)\r\n   в System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)\r\n   в VideoMessager.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() в C:\\Users\\Medhelp\\source\\repos\\VideoMessager\\VideoMessager\\MainWindow.xaml:строка 1"   string`

Model, которая с текстом и работает

```
class TestText : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void UpdateText(Action<string> action)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            action(i.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateFrame(Action<BitmapSource> updateDelegate)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string name = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
            for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
            {

                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/" + name + ";Component/Img/frame_" + i.ToString() + "_delay-0.08s.gif"));
                updateDelegate(image);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using VideoMessager.Models;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace VideoMessager.ViewModels
{
    public delegate void UpdateImagesDelegate(BitmapImage image);
    class Main : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private VideoCall video;
        public VideoCall Video
        {
            get
            {
                return video;
            }
            set
            {
                video = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Video");
            }
        }

        private BitmapSource imageFrame;
        public BitmapSource ImageFrame
        {
            get
            {
                return imageFrame;
            }
            set
            {
                imageFrame = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImageFrame");
            }
        }

        private string testText;
        public string TestText
        {
            get
            {
                return testText;
            }
            set
            {
                testText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TestText");
            }
        }

        public TestText test = new TestText();

        public Main()
        {
            Video = new VideoCall(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 5600);


            var UpdateFrame = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                 test.UpdateText(UpdateUI);
                test.UpdateFrame(UpdateImage);
            });
        }

        public void UpdateImage(BitmapSource image)
        {
            ImageFrame = image; 
        }

        public void UpdateUI(string s)
        {
            TestText = s;
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<Window
    x:Class="VideoMessager.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VideoMessager"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:VideoMessager.ViewModels"
    Title="Main"
    Width="300"
    Height="300"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:Main />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Image
            Width="272"
            Height="212"
            Margin="10,26,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Source="{Binding Path=ImageFrame, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Button
            Width="134"
            Margin="148,243,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Content="Выбрать" />
        <Button
            Width="133"
            Margin="10,243,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Content="Отправить" />
        <TextBox
            Width="120"
            Height="23"
            Margin="106,35,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Text="{Binding Path=TestText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: 1) вся работа связанная с отображением должна производиться во `View`, а не в модели и не в вьюмодели. 2) обновление изображений и текста через равные промежутки времени лучше всего производить с помощью анимации, логика которой пишется прямо в `XAML`.

Comment: Почему ваш дизайн ошибочен, написал Bulson. А как разобраться с многопоточностью, можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615113/10105).

Comment: Добавил Freeze() и заработало.