# Пауза во время цикла c#

Tags: c#, циклы

Если использовать в цикле паузу System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000), то на паузу ставится вся программа. Мне нужно, чтобы во время паузы в цикле я мог нажимать на кнопки Windows Forms.

Comment: Во время нажатия на кнопку я буду выходить из цикла.

Comment: Может вам подойдет лучше Timer с интервалом 1000 мс?

Comment: Какой из таймеров?
У меня не получается их использовать, не могу найти документацию и примеры.

Comment: Вызывай метод асихронно. Форма не будет лочится, но System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) звучит(((( Зачем он тебе вообще?

Comment: Рисую график, и в промежуток между новыми значениями нужно нажать на одну из кнопок.

Comment: Вот вам [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/762697/222542).

Answer (score 0):

Простой пример запуска таймера потом его использования. Первой кнопкой запускаем таймер, который увеличивает i. Второй кнопкой помещаем i в поле.
Таким способом можно решить Вашу проблему. Программа не будет зависать.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int i = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = i.ToString();

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

}

UPD В вашем случае цикла не будет, а будет вызываться нужный код в самом таймере (например там будет вызов функции, которая ранее была у Вас в цикле)

Для остановки цикла можно использовать timer1.Enabled = false; , который вызывать при нажатии кнопки