# Программа зависает на время обработки цикла. Как исправить?

Tags: c#, wpf

Пишу программу вопросник, по типу "Кто хочет стать миллионером?". Использую связку page и frame для навигации по страницам. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователю в цикле задавалось 15 вопросов, которые бы последовательно менялись. Т.е. как только пользователь правильно ответил на текущий вопрос, условное i увеличивается на 1, появляется следующий вопрос и игра продолжается так до конца. Однако, при переходе на page с самой игрой программа зависает пока цикл не дойдет до конца. Проблема в том, что именно это мне не нужно. Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить или как правильно сделать паузы между вопросами.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
{
    do
    {
        number = rnd.Next(1, 147);
        ok = false;
        while (number % 5 != 0)
        {
            number = number - 1;
        }
        number++;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(readpath, Encoding.Default))
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= number + 4; j++)
            {
                string line;
                line = sr.ReadLine(); /*colvo <= 5*/
                if (j == number)
                {
                    mas[i].Text = line;
                }
                if (j == number + 1)
                {
                    mas[i].TrueAnswer = line;
                }
                if (j == number + 2)
                {
                    mas[i].FalseAnswer1 = line;
                }
                if (j == number + 3)
                {
                    mas[i].FalseAnswer2 = line;
                }
                if (j == number + 4)
                {
                    mas[i].FalseAnswer3 = line;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= 15; k++)
        {
            if (mas[k].Text == mas[i].Text && k != i)
            {
                ok = false;
            }
            else
            {
                ok = true;
            }
        }
        lbl_question.Content = mas[i].Text;
        true_answer = mas[i].TrueAnswer;
        lbl_B.Content = mas[i].FalseAnswer1;
        lbl_C.Content = mas[i].FalseAnswer2;
        lbl_D.Content = mas[i].FalseAnswer3;

        rnd_znach = rnd.Next(1, 4);
        if (rnd_znach == 1)
        {
            lbl_A.Content = mas[i].TrueAnswer;
        }
        if (rnd_znach == 2)
        {
            lbl_A.Content = lbl_B.Content;
            lbl_B.Content = mas[i].TrueAnswer;
        }
        if (rnd_znach == 3)
        {
            lbl_A.Content = lbl_C.Content;
            lbl_C.Content = mas[i].TrueAnswer;
        }
        if (rnd_znach == 4)
        {
            lbl_A.Content = lbl_D.Content;
            lbl_D.Content = mas[i].TrueAnswer;
        }
    } while (!ok);
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615113/10105

Comment: В вашем случае цикл не нужен. Вы в памяти должны держать коллекцию вопросов, при ответе на вопрос, при нажатии на кнопку вызываете след. вопрос из этой коллекции. Для этого можно использовать очередь `Queue<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, на самом деле всё просто. Давайте я просто подскажу вам логику:
Вам понадобится в классе поле, например int _index. Это поле будет хранить текущий номер вопроса.
Затем создать метод, который будет отображать вопрос и варианты ответа на него. Этот метод будет брать текущий индекс, получать по нему вопрос из общего массива вопросов и отображать.
Когда игрок даёт любой ответ, вы проверяете его на истину/ложь после чего увеличиваете или нет очки (или прерываете игру, в случае ошибки, как вам угодно), увеличиваете индекс и вызываете метод, который отображает вопрос.
При переходе на страницу в первый раз вам нужно выставить индекс равный нулю и вызвать метод отображения.