# Не работает цикл в отдельном потоке WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Программа запускается, но не выводит интерфейс

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Browser.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    InitializeComponent();
    Main.Content = new Pages.MainPage();

    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            RuCaptchaBalance.Text = Rucaptcha.GetBalance();
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: А где тут отдельный поток-то?

Comment: Там, где this.Dispatcher

Comment: Нет, этот цикл выполняется в основном потоке

Comment: А как сделать в отдельном? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: new Thread или Task.Run

Comment: Тогда программа запускается, но вылетает

Comment: Ну так проблему вылета и нужно решать. Однако при ее решении нельзя "терять" фоновой поток.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, вы хотите вот что:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Browser.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    InitializeComponent();
    Main.Content = new Pages.MainPage();

    RunMainLoop();
}

async void RunMainLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        RuCaptchaBalance.Text = await Task.Run(() => Rucaptcha.GetBalance());
        await Task.Delay(1000); // делаем вычисления не подряд, а через разумную паузу
    }
}
```

По поводу теории, почему так, почитайте [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615113/10105).

Comment: Работает, спасибо

Comment: @TwilightOwl: Куда оно денется? Пожалуйста.