# Почему дочерний поток тормозит работу интерфейса формы?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

По нажатию кнопки запускаю отдельный поток, в котором выполняется бесконечный цикл, периодически засыпая на 2-3 секунды. Почему то при этом перестает отвечать и интерфейс формы.
Так запускаю:

```
Thread loop = new Thread(MainLoop);
loop.Start();
```

Так выглядит метод, выполняющий цикл:

```
public void MainLoop(){
    while(loopEnabled){
    //работа цикла
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    } 

}
```

Как выполнять какие либо операции в отдельном потоке, не блокируя при этом интерфейс?

Comment: приведите весь необходимый для воспроизведения проблемы код, так как по тому кусочку, что вы показываете, ничего сказать нельзя

Comment: `Как выполнять какие либо операции в отдельном потоке, не блокируя при этом интерфейс? ` Ответ смотрим [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/785182/222542)