# Убрать задержку при отправке почты в приложении WInForms

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня в приложении есть окно отправки оценки на почту. И при нажатии кнопки `Send` приложение грузится секунд 20, а потом сообщение с успехом. Можно ли как-то убрать вот ту задержку в виде 20 секунд?

```
private void SendMail()
{
    string fromUser = richTextBox1.Text;
    int mark = trackBar1.Value;
    string uemail = textBox1.Text;
    try
    {
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress(uemail);
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("vgolovatyukx@gmail.com");
        MailMessage m = new MailMessage(from, to);
        m.Subject = "Твое приложение оценили!";
        m.IsBodyHtml = false;
        m.Body = "Your mark is " + mark + "\n" + fromUser;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("vgolovatyukx@gmail.com", "_________"),
            EnableSsl = true
        };
        smtp.Send(m);
        MessageBox.Show("Сообщение успешно отправлено. Спасибо!");
        Close();
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Неверный формат электронной почты. Почта должна иметь окончания - @gmail/yandex/mail/bk/list и другие");
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Строка с адресом не должна быть пуста");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.HelpLink);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/785182/222542

Comment: `new NetworkCredential("vgolovatyukx@gmail.com", "_________")` А вы точно уверены, что хотите оставлять в программе логин-пароль от своей почты?

Comment: почта новая, к ней нечего не привязано

Comment: @Bulson а можете указать куда и что с async await не работал ранее

Comment: В примере по ссылке весь код снабжен комментариями, что где и зачем. Вам достаточно внимательно прочитать и попытаться повторить, но без токена отмены и отображения хода выполнения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если пишете на .NET 4.5+, сделайте все методы (вплоть до обработчика события) асинхронными, и используйте метод [SendMailAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh193922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) вместо Send:

```
await smtp.SendMailAsync(m);
```

На более старых версиях - вынести в BackgroundWorker, я думаю. Или  воспользоваться [SendAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx), который потребует вынесения кода в callback.