# Как правильно, в WPF в рамках паттерна MVVM подключить Progressbar

Tags: c#, wpf

Собираюсь в своем приложении сделать индикатор процесса, и сейчас встал вопрос, а как правильно подключить Прогрессбар, чтобы он вписался в паттерн.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/785182/222542

Comment: @Bulson Спасибо, то что нужно