# Изменить переменную в бесконечном цикле

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно чтобы переменная `proverkaTimera` менялась в необходимом интервале времени с `false` на `true` и бесконечный цикл заходил бы в тело условия `if (proverkaTimera)`

Пробовал так и как в ответе ниже от `trydex`:

```
private void Algoritm()
{
    bool proverkaTimera = false;

    var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0, 0);
    timer.Start();

    for (;;)
    {
       if (proverkaTimera)
       {
          ...
          proverkaTimera = false;
       }

       ...
    }
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   proverkaTimera = true;
}
```

Ещё пробовал так, но в этом случае, откладывается выполнение остальной части когда пока пока не выполнится сам блок `if`.

```
private async void Algoritm()
{
    bool timerTick = false;

    for (;;)
    {

       timerTick = await Timer();

       if (timerTick)
       {
          ...
          timerTick = false;
       }

       ...
    }
}

private async Task<bool> Timer() 
{
        await Task.Delay(10000);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: А в чем проблема, собственно?

Comment: @АндрейNOP: думаю ТС не знает о лямбдах, которые могут захватывать данные.

Comment: Разве при таком цикле `for (;;)` событие таймера вызовется?

Comment: @АндрейNOP проблема в том, что в таком виде `Timer_Tick` не знает о переменой

Comment: @Vipz Это-то как раз не проблема - сделайте переменную членом класса.

Comment: А зачем вам этот таймер? Что за алгоритм у вас?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615113/10105

Comment: @Igor как это делается на моём примере ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не совсем понимаю, почему все *зациклились* :) на лямбдах и замыканиях. Замыкание, конечно, удобно в данном случае, но член класса тоже сработает. Гораздо хуже здесь то (если я правильно понимаю, как работает `DispatcherTimer`), что плотный цикл не даст вызваться событию таймера.

Используйте `System.Threading.Timer` вместо `DispatcherTimer` и

```
bool proverkaTimera = false;

private void Algoritm()
{
  proverkaTimera = false;
  ...
```

Comment: Здорово, спасибо Вам ! А то перепробовал абсолютно каждый комментарий и всё не выходило, думал уже руки опустятся. Просто что не загуглю, везде `DispatcherTimer` используется, а с `System.Threading.Timer` всё просто, передал какой метод нужно использовать, передал переменную (правда получается что глобальную), указал интервал и всё работает как надо !

Comment: @Vipz Я рад, что код заработал. Помните, что событие таймера, выполняемое в отдельном потоке, накладывает дополнительные требования к коду в этом событии. Доступ к элементам GUI должен быть синхронизирован с основным потоком.

Comment: Да, я сейчас подробнее про него почитаю, чтобы знать с чем имею дело.

Answer (score 1):

Как вам и подсказали в комментариях это можно сделать через лямбду, которая будет захватывать вашу переменную.

То есть вместо создания отдельного обработчика события таким образом:

```
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
```

мы можем подписать [лямбда-выражение](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.16.php) вот так:

```
timer.Tick += (s, e) => { proverkaTimera = true;};
```

О замыканиях можете почитать [здесь](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2010/04/c.html).

---

Также можно вместо локальной переменной сделать поле или свойство, тогда вы сможете к ней обращаться из вашего метода `Timer_Tick` в текущей реализации.

То есть ваш класс видоизменится до такого:

```
class Example
{
    private bool proverkaTimera;

    private void Algoritm()
    {
        proverkaTimera = false;

        //Остальной код
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        proverkaTimera = true;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: несколько раз пробовал делать это, но не резу бесконечный цикл не зашёл в тело `if (proverkaTimera)`

Comment: @Vipz, Это уже другой вопрос и об этом вам также говорили в комментариях. Событие не сработает т.к. поток занят бесконечным циклом. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос и опишите, что конкретно вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Я написал прям под кодом что мне нужно.

Comment: @Vipz, Я имел ввиду опишите картину в общем, что должен делать ваш метод?. Пока все выглядит так, что вы делаете в корне не верно. От бесконечного цикла нужно, скорее всего, нужно избавляться.

Answer (score 1):

Нет никакого смысла в таймере, который всего лишь устанавливает переменную! Если вам нужно отслеживать наступление некоторого момента времени - то для этих целей существует класс `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)))
{
    for(;;) 
    {
        if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // 10 минут прошли
        }
    }
}
```

Бонусом идет возможность дождаться наступления события

```
ctx.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
```

а также получить сигнал о его наступлении используя метод Register.