# Как сделать переменную членом класса?

Tags: c#

Как сделать переменную `cheked` членом класса `timer` ?

```
bool cheked = false;

var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
```

Comment: Никак (один два три)

Comment: Унаследовать, если это возможно, от класса DispatcherTimer с новым полем и пользоваться новым классом. Только не понимаю,  зачем вам это...

Comment: @KirillRunk один из советов к этому вопросу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/889633/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-dispatchertimer

Comment: Просто событие на `tick` пишите лямбда выражением, и передавать ничего не поидется

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц можно пример

Comment: просто объявите её не в вашей функции, а в самом классе

Comment: Выучите лямбды и замыкания, без них никуда.

Comment: @Vipz имелось в виду - членом класса, чей метод Вы используете в качестве обработчика события `timer.Tick`. Tо есть просто вынести декларацию `bool proverkaTimera;` из метода `Algoritm` в тело класса, который содержит этот метод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class DispTimer : DispatcherTimer {
    public bool checked { set; get; }
    public DispTimer() => checked = false;
}
var timer = DispTimer();
```