# WPF. Не обновляется Textbox с Bind при отсутствии действий от пользователя

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть Textbox, на который привязано некоторое значение:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding LastUpdateTimeString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Для свойства LastUpdateTimeString реализован INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
            string lastUpdateTimeString;
            public string LastUpdateTimeString
            {
                get { return lastUpdateTimeString; }
                set { lastUpdateTimeString = value; Console.WriteLine("updated on " + lastUpdateTimeString); OnPropertyChanged(); }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
```

Свойство обновляется из другого потока каждую секунду:

```
void devicePollingThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                List<ControlParameter> controlParametersLocalList = new List<ControlParameter>(ParameterList);

                foreach(ControlParameter controlParameter in controlParametersLocalList)
                    controlParameter.LastUpdateTimeString= DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
```

При работе приложения, указанное поле обновляется каждую секунду, если есть какие-то действия от пользователя - водить мышкой по разным элементам, перетаскивать окно по рабочему столу. Если оставить мышку в покое и ничего не делать, то TextBox перестает обновляться. Выводом в консоль проверял, что фактически свойство меняется каждую секунду, но не происходит обновления именно самого Textbox.

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: покажите код этого свойства `LastUpdateTimeString`

Comment: @tym32167 Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: `{Binding Path=LastUpdateTimeString}`    попробуйте так, и уберите `Console.WriteLine("updated on...` в OnPropertyChanged("LastUpdateTimeString") надо вставить имя меняемой переменной.

Comment: @NewView Результат тот же. Через этот вывод в консоль я вижу, что переменная фактически меняется. Передавать параметр в OnPropertyChanged я тоже попробовал, но с использованием System.Runtime.CompilerServices и CallerMemberName это и так происходит автоматически.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В дополнение к в общем-то верному ответу: действительно, в исходном коде была ошибка: изменения свойств, к которым происходит привязка, обязано происходить в UI-потоке. Иначе возможны все виды ошибок, чаще всего это заканчивается крешем.

Я бы на вашем месте отказался от устаревшего `BackgroundWorker`'а, и переписал бы код на async/await (и запускал его в UI-потоке):

```
async Task DevicePolling()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var controlParametersLocalList = new List<ControlParameter>(ParameterList);

        // если тут нужен реальный опрос устройств, проводите его на пуле потоков, как-то так:
        await Task.Run(() => { тут ваш потенциально медленный блокирующий код; });

        foreach(var controlParameter in controlParametersLocalList)
            controlParameter.LastUpdateTimeString = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [Почему Thread.Sleep ведёт себя неправильно? Как мне сделать задержку или длинные вычисления в графической программе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615113/10105)

Answer (score 1):

Получилось сделать так.

В класс, где живет поток для обработки проблемного свойства добавил:

```
SynchronizationContext uiContext;
```

В конструкторе этого класса:

```
uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

И в самом потоке:

```
        void devicePollingThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                List<ControlParameter> controlParametersLocalList = new List<ControlParameter>(ParameterList);

                foreach(ControlParameter controlParameter in controlParametersLocalList)
                    uiContext.Send(x => controlParameter.LastUpdateTimeString= DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), null);

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
```

Пойду теперь подтягивать теорию - почему не работало без этого.