# ListView не получается вывести текст в строках по порядку

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, list

Как сделать чтобы выводило текст в каждой строке по порядку, т.е. сперва: Строка № - 1, Строка № - 2 и т.д..., у меня получилось, что появляются все сразу 10 строк. Что я делаю не правильно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Window x:Class="TestVoid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestVoid"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding AllModel}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Temp, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

```
 public delegate void TestDelegateVoid(string message);
public class Test
{
    public void TestVoid(TestDelegateVoid method)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            method(String.Format($"Строка № - {i} "));
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
}

  public class Model
    {
        public delegate int TestDelegate(string message);

        List<string> temp = new List<string>();
        public List<string> Temp { get => temp; set { temp = value; } }
    public Model()
    {
        Main();
    }

        void Main()
        {
            Test test = new Test();
            TestDelegateVoid method = ShowMessage;
            test.TestVoid(method);
        }
        void ShowMessage(string message)
        {
            Temp.Add(message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если это должна быть строка, то и отображайте ее как строку. Сделайте свойство, например `public string StringTemp => string.Join(",", Temp);` и привязывайте его к текстовому представлению (например `TextBlock`). Если вам это нужно отображать все же как массив, то переопределите у вашего `ListView` в XAML `ItemsPanel`, задав например там `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />`, тогда все ваши элементы будут отображены в один ряд.

Comment: Я прошу прощения, но мне не получается правильно составить вопрос, я хотел что бы текст который появляется в столбике на картинке которую я привязал, печатался поочередно т.е сперва строка 1, далее предположим через две секунды строка 2 и т.д.

Comment: Вы в метод sleep передаёте значение "10". Там время задаётся в миллисекундах т.е. 1/1000 секунды. Так что строки у вас появляются с задержкой 1/100 секунды, поэтому вы этого не замечаете. Попробуйте увеличить задержку до секунды

Comment: Я увеличил до 1000, компилятор запускает -> потом за кадром долгое ожидание и после уже появляется весь текст.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Почему Thread.Sleep ведёт себя неправильно? Как мне сделать задержку или длинные вычисления в графической программе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615113/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-thread-sleep-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%91%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

```
public async void TestVoid(TestDelegateVoid method)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        method(String.Format($"Строка № - {i} "));
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```